# Authorization with JAX-RS 1 (Jersey) using e.g @RolesAllowed

Tags: java, rest

If I use JAX-RS 2 it's so easy, like below.

But the problem is doing this using the previous version. I don't know how to do it.

```
@Provider
public class SomeFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        Method method = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a filter. Add the security constraint `auth-constraint` in the web.xml. Following sample shows how you can add two roles called staff and customer to the authorized roles.

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>staff</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>customer</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Read-only REST requests</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/weather/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>customer</role-name>
        <role-name>staff</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint> … </security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
</login-config>
```